# How can I access the the Astro config values in a page?

Tags: config, astrojs

I have an Astro project with an `astro.config.mjs` configured with a `site` value.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  site: 'https://example.com',
  // ...etc
})
```

In my layout, I have `<meta>` tags that have the same URL hard coded in them.

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/social.png" />
```

I would like to be able to access the `site` config value to replace all the hard coded URLs.

```js
<meta property="og:url" content={config.site} />
<meta property="og:image" content={`${config.site}/social.png`} />
```

How can I access the config values from within a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site can be accessed on the `Astro.site` global. This is documented [here](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astrosite). The `Astro.site` value is a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object.

To use it in your frontmatter.

```js
const origin = Astro.site.origin
```

To get a string of the full URL.

```js
const site = Astro.site.href
// or
const site = Astro.site.toString()
```

To use it directly in your HTML.

```js
<meta property="og:url" content={Astro.site} />
<meta property="og:image" content={`${Astro.site}social.png`} />
```